# Check if date in past

Tags: powershell

```
$olddate = Get-Date -Date "31-dec-2013 00:00:00" -Format d.M.yyyy
$Now = Get-date -Format d.M.yyyy
```

How can I check if $olddate is earlier than $Now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your store them as `DateTime` instead of as formatted strings, you can use the less-than operator (`-lt`) just like with regular numbers, and then use the format operator (`-f`) when you need to actually display the date:

```
$olddate = Get-Date -Date "31-dec-2013 00:00:00"
$Now = Get-Date 
if($olddate -lt $Now){
    "`$olddate is in the past!"
    "{0:d.M.yyyy}" -f $olddate
    "{0:d.M.yyyy}" -f $Now
}
```

Comment: **Updated answer** - When you use `-Format` with `Get-Date`, the output is just a string, wait until you actually need to display or output it to format the string, this way you won't lose "comparability"

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a comparison on Ticks. I.e.: `$olddate.Ticks` will be `-lt` then `$Now.Ticks`.